# embed video shows "Video unavailable Watch on YouTube" on certain devices

Tags: youtube

On Mac (tried on Safari, Chrome and Safari)

This link doesn't work:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/OFd-HJyqxNw
But if you click on the "watch on YouTube" link, the video is available

This link works:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/lTtKyRSjBOI

On Window both links works on chrome and edge.

I wonder why? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.